# Are there any common Design patterns or common idioms that are important for C++ win32 multithreading programming?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, design-patterns, idioms

One example could be: RAII - Resource Acquisition is Initialization used with critical sections

Any others that are important, popular and you often use?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/patterns-ace.html) mentions quite a few.  The Command pattern comes in handy for dispatching requests to threads.  Leader/Followers seems to be an interesting pattern as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also: [patterns and idioms](http://paulbridger.net/multithreading_patterns_and_idioms)

Answer (score 0):

I use [message passing, share nothing concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) both for my current product and for high performance desktop applications I have written in the past. In my experience, its better to avoid shared data synchronization. You can use NamedPipes, window messages or sockets to communicate between threads.

If you do decide to try and syncronize access to shared data, [take a look at this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520837/what-are-common-concurrency-pitfalls/520920#520920)